# Continuity of length under uniform convergence

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(\phi_n):[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a sequence of injective curves, parameterized by constant speed, uniformly converging to a limit curve $\phi:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^d$. Assume:

1. $\sup_n |\phi_n'|<+\infty$, i.e. uniform bound on lengths,
2. $\sup_n\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{|s-t|^2}{|\phi_n(s)-\phi_n(t)|^2} ds\ dt<+\infty $,
   hence all curves $\phi_n$ are injective,
3. $\sup_n \|\phi_n'\|_{TV}<+\infty$, where $\|\cdot\|_{TV}$ denotes the total variation. This means that the (generalized) total curvature of curves $\phi_n$ is uniformly bounded.

All these conditions are required (dropping (1) is meaningless for my context, dropping (2) or (3) leads to easy counterexamples).
I want to show that in this case the length passes to the limit, i.e.
$$\int_0^1 |\phi'| ds = \lim_n \int_0^1 |\phi_n'| ds,$$
and can do in 2 dimensions (by splitting $\phi_n'$ into components, working first on piece-wise linear curves, then argue by density). However I am stuck for higher dimensions (the main point is that the projection does not decreases the curvature in general).

Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you.